# How to fix unintentional BC break in composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php

We're sticking to semantic versioning with our packages. We unintentionally created a BC break in minor version. Some people are already using that version.

What is a good way to fix this mistake? Ideally we'd prevent composer from ever considering the offending version, but still allow to install if it's locked on it, so that we don't break other people's code...

Is there a best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd immediately release next patch version which fixes this mistake and point it out with bold text in readme. It is the same immutable principle as in `git revert`. It makes the less damage imo. It may only cost developers one `composer update` to fix.